# php shell_exec triggers a job twice

Tags: php, bash, curl, shell-exec

There is an issue I couldn't find the exact problem, or is it a problem anyway I don't know.

I execute below command through shell_exec in php. I'm user I called just once.

> curl -o ./server.log --request POST 'crawlserver.xxx.local/workerCallback.php' --user-agent 'xxx' --data 'workerid=worker1&jobid=25&offercount=72&file='/path/to/xxx-2014-02-07-serialized.txt'

this command working like 30 seconds.

while when I ask to bash as `ps aux | grep workerCallback`

I see 2 different commands triggered, and different process ids. But when look to server.log file it is looking a single request, also I check db and other stuff, the request worked single. But why it is looking twice in commandline by different pids, and commands has little differences. What is the "sh -c" before the command.

> 1000     27384  0.0  0.0   4404   612 ?        S    14:00   0:00 sh -c curl -o ./server.log --request POST 'crawlserver.xxx.local/workerCallback.php' --user-agent 'xxx' --data 'workerid=worker1&jobid=25&offercount=72&file=path/to/xxx-2014-02-07-serialized.txt'
>
> 1000     27385  0.0  0.0  88056  3756 ?        S    14:00   0:00 curl -o ./server.log --request POST crawlserver.xxx.local/workerCallback.php --user-agent xxx --data workerid=worker1&jobid=25&offercount=72&file=/path/to/xxx-2014-02-07-serialized.txt

Comment: 1. open a shell to exec command 2. exec command = 2 tasks

Comment: When you do `ps aux | grep workerCallback` you must get 2-4 proccesses, too, one is the ps, one is grep, and one (or more) is the result

Comment: Yes Dan, I understand it now. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not the same command twice, the first command is the shell (sh) running your curl command.

The second one is the command itself.

So your code is working fine :)

Comment: results show me its working fine :) but I couldn't understand logic here could you please give me detailed explanation ?

Comment: You have to think about what shell exec does. It uses a shell (sh) to run a command. In Linux when you are running any commands you are more than likely doing that using a shell such as sh or more usually bash. So that is what is happening here